# Android Alarm Manager Issue

Tags: android, eclipse, alarmmanager

Ive been at this for 7 days now. How do you start a service with an alarm manager?
I did this in a different script but it is not working on this one.

```
       if(alarmManager != null)
            alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);

        alarmIntentNot = new Intent(AlarmService.this, ActiveAlarmService.class);

        alarmIntentNot.putExtra(MainActivity.ALARM_VIBRATE, alarm.vibrate);
        alarmIntentNot.putExtra(MainActivity.ALARM_SOUND_OVERRIDE, alarm.soundOverride);
        alarmIntentNot.putExtra(MainActivity.ALARM_TIME_TO_MAX, alarm.timeToMax);
        alarmIntentNot.putExtra(MainActivity.ALARM_VOLUME, alarm.volume);

        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmService.this, 0, alarmIntentNot, 0);    

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);              
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

I dont see anything invalid there. In my Manifest i have:

```
     <service android:name="com.androidoverapple.schoolscancelledalarmclock.ActiveAlarmService" android:enabled="true">
    </service>
```

Ive google to no end. The service does not start. All of my log cat stuff says it is being set and it just doesnt start the service.

Comment: you never call `startService`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Because i need the alarm manager needs to start the service at the right time. :)

Comment: But you're problem is "My service never starts". That is why. In the code you showed us you never start the service because you literally never call `startService`...

Comment: Alarm Managers are supposed to start activites and services.